# Updating a list of options in the child when updating the parent state

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

My list of options (domains) based on the selected course is updated in the parent state, but the child won't update/inherit the prop sent with it. The child needs to receive the domains state from the parent and make up a option list out of it. It works on initialize, but won't update after the change of course in the parent component.

AddQuestion.js

```
class AddQuestion extends Component {

  constructor(props){
      super(props)

      // initiate all states
      this.state = {
        course: '',
        domains: []
      }

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <MainQuestion formError={this.state.formError} levels={this.state.levels} years={this.state.years} courses={this.state.courses} introductionlist={this.state.introductionlist} subQuestions={this.state.subQuestions} numSubQuestion={this.state.numSubQuestion} handleCourseChange={this.handleCourseChange} postQuestion={this.postQuestion} addSubQuestion={this.addSubQuestion} formHasError={this.state.formHasError} validateForm={this.validateForm}/>
    );
  }

  // handle onchange course input
  handleCourseChange = (e) => {
     this.setState({
       course: e.target.value
     },
     function(e) {
      console.log(this.state.course);
      this.getResponseDomains();
      },
     this.validateForm(e)
   );
  }

  // get domains based on course
  getResponseDomains = () => {

    console.log(this.state.course);
    // fetch data from backend
    axios.get('/api/domain/get?course=' + this.state.course, {
      course: this.state.course
    })
    .then(response => response.data.data)
    .then((json) => {

      json.map(obj => this.setState({domains: Object.values(obj) }));
      this.state.domains = json;

      // map a option input for each fetched domain
      let domainslist = Object.keys(this.state.domains).map(key =>
        <option label={this.state.domains[key].name} value={this.state.domains[key].id} />
      )

      this.setState({
        domains: domainslist
      });

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

  // Add the input field to a new subquestion
  addSubQuestion = () => {
    this.setState({
      numSubQuestion: this.state.numSubQuestion + 1,
      formHasError: true
    });

    //reset array
    subQuestions = [];

    let errormessages = '';
    let errornum = this.state.numSubQuestion + 1;

    //fill array for amount of subquestions needed
    for (var i = 0; i <= this.state.numSubQuestion; i += 1) {
      subQuestions.push(<SubQuestion key={i} number={i + 1} domain={this.state.domain} course={this.state.course} domains={this.state.domains} subjects={this.state.subjects} />);

    this.setState({
      subQuestions: subQuestions,
      formError: errormessages
    });

  }
```

MainQuestion.js

```
// This is the main question (e.d. level, year, course and introduction)
class MainQuestion extends Component {

  constructor(props){
      super(props)

  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="addQuestion-wrapper">
        <div className="logo mx-auto">
          <img src="/img/logo-white.png"/>
        </div>
        <section className="addQuestion container">
          <form id="addQuestionForm">
            <p className="text-danger">{ this.props.formError }</p> {/* display errors */}
            <div className="row d-flex prequestion">
              <div className="col-12 mb-3">
                <h2>Nieuwe vraag toevoegen</h2>
              </div>
              <div ref="error3" className="input-group col-12 col-lg-6" id="levels-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <p className="label">Niveau</p>
                  {this.props.levels} {/* display fetched levels */}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div ref="error4" className="input-group col-12 col-lg-6" id="years-wrapper">
                <div>
                  <p className="label">Leerjaar</p>
                  {this.props.years} {/* display fetched years */}
                </div>
              </div>
              <div ref="error5" className="input-group col-12 col-lg-6">
              <p className="label">Vak</p>
                <select onChange={this.props.handleCourseChange} name="course" id="select-courses">
                  <option value="" disabled selected>--Kies een vak</option>
                  {this.props.courses} {/* display fetched courses */}
                </select>
              </div>
              <div ref="error10" className="input-group col-12 col-lg-12">
                {this.props.introductionlist} {/* display created introduction textarea */}
              </div>

              </div>

              { this.props.subQuestions } {/* display amount of subquestions in the array */}

              {/* add subquestion button */}
              <div className="AddSubquestion">
                <button className="btn" onClick={ this.props.addSubQuestion } disabled={this.props.formHasError}>Subvraag toevoegen</button>
              </div>

              {/* post question button */}
              <div className="input-group" id="submit">
                <button className="btn" onClick={ this.props.postQuestion } value="Aanmaken" disabled={this.props.formHasError}>Verzend</button>
              </div>

          </form>
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }



}

export default AddQuestion;
```

SubQuestion.js

```
class SubQuestion extends Component {

  constructor(props){
      super(props)

      // initiate all states
      this.state = {
        course: props.course,
        domains: []
      }

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row d-flex justify-content-center question mt-5">
        <div className="col-12">
          <h3> Subvraag {this.props.number} </h3> {/* display number of subquestion. Fetched from key of created child component */}
        </div>
        <div ref="error" className="input-group col-12 col-lg-6" id="type-wrapper">
          {this.state.type} {/* display fetched type */}
        </div>
        <div ref="error2" className="input-group col-12 col-lg-6" id="questionings-wrapper">
          <div>
            <p className="label">Vraagstelling</p>
            {this.state.questionings} {/* display fetched questionings */}
          </div>
        </div>
        <div ref="error6" className="input-group col-12 col-lg-12">
          {this.state.question} {/* display created textarea for questiona AND answer */}
        </div>
        <div ref="error7" className="input-group col-12 col-lg-6">
          <p className="label">Domein</p>
          <select id="select-domains" name={`domain-${this.props.number}`} onChange={this.handleDomainChange}>
            <option value="" disabled selected>--Kies een domein</option>
            {this.props.domains} {/* display fetched domains */}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div ref="error8" className="input-group col-12 col-lg-6" id="select-subjects">
          <p className="label">Onderwerp</p>
          <select onChange={this.props.handleSubjectChange} name={`subject-${this.props.number}`}>
            <option value="" disabled selected>--Kies een onderwerp</option>
            {this.state.subjects} {/* display fetched subjects */}
          </select>
        </div>
        <div ref="error9" className="input-group col-12 col-lg-12" id="time-points-rtti">
          <div className="time mr-4">
            {/* display time input */}
            <p className="label">Tijdsduur</p>
            <input type="number" name={`tijdsduur-${this.props.number}`} min="1" placeholder="tijd in minuten" onChange={this.props.handleTimeChange}/>
          </div>
          <div className="points mr-4">
            {/* display points input */}
            <p className="label">Punten</p>
            <input type="number" name={`points-${this.props.number}`} min="1" placeholder="punten" onChange={this.props.handlePointsChange}/>
          </div>
          <div className="rtti">
            {/* display rtti input */}
            <p className="label">RTTI</p>
            <input type="radio" name={`RTTI-${this.props.number}`} id={`R-${this.props.number}`} value="1" onChange={this.props.handleRttiChange}/><label htmlFor={`R-${this.props.number}`}>R</label>
            <input type="radio" name={`RTTI-${this.props.number}`} id={`T1-${this.props.number}`} value="2" onChange={this.props.handleRttiChange}/><label htmlFor={`T1-${this.props.number}`}>T1</label>
            <input type="radio" name={`RTTI-${this.props.number}`} id={`T2-${this.props.number}`} value="3" onChange={this.props.handleRttiChange}/><label htmlFor={`T2-${this.props.number}`}>T2</label>
            <input type="radio" name={`RTTI-${this.props.number}`} id={`I-${this.props.number}`} value="4" onChange={this.props.handleRttiChange}/><label htmlFor={`I-${this.props.number}`}>I</label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    );
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
      this.setState({course: nextProps.course, domains: nextProps.domains });
  }

// handle onchange domain input
  handleDomainChange = (e) => {
     this.setState({
       domain: e.target.value
     },
     this.getResponseSubjects, // change subjects based on selected domain
     this.props.validateForm(e)
    );
  }

  // get subjects based on domain
  getResponseSubjects = () => {

    // fetch data from backend
    axios.get('/api/subject/get?domain=' + this.state.domain, {
      domain: this.state.domain
    })
    .then(response => response.data.data)
    .then((json) => {

      json.map(obj => this.setState({subjects: Object.values(obj) }));
      this.state.subjects = json;

      // map a option input for each fetched subject
      let subjectslist = Object.keys(this.state.subjects).map(key =>
        <option label={this.state.subjects[key].name} value={this.state.subjects[key].id} />
      )

      this.setState({
        subjects: subjectslist
      }
      );

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
  }

export default SubQuestion;
```

The expected result would be the child component changing the domains based on the course. These variables are changed the parent AddQuestion, but don't come thru as prop in the child.

Answer (score 0):

At first glance you're doing this:

```
handleCourseChange = (e) => {
     this.setState({
       course: e.target.value
     },
     function(e) {
      console.log(this.state.course);
      this.getResponseDomains();
      },
     this.validateForm(e)
   );
  }
```

If I'm right that callback after setState doesn't know what `this` is, because you're declaring a full function instead of an arrow function. Regular functions don't inherit `this`, they have it undefined by default.

Comment: Hi Alex, Thanks for your response. The console.log does actually log the this.state.course correctly. It also reaches the this.getResponseDomains, I have a console.log there too.

Comment: Ah sorry my bad then. Looking further I'm not sure how to help cause I'm confused by why you're setting state manually both for subjects and domains: first you set it as a parsed JSON with `this.state.domains = json;` and then you're setting state properly with setState to an array of JSX elements: `this.setState({domains:domainslist });` . Are you sure that's what you're trying to do?

Comment: No problem. Yeah, I actually need to do some React 16 > React 18 fixing like setting the states with setState instead of manually, so don't focus on that too much. The JSON is to fetch API data which I then use in the form as option in a select input.

Comment: Outside of what I already mentioned I'm not seeing anything obvious. I'm assuming you're not getting any errors and that the network requests actually work and return properly. What I'd do is console log the domains object every step of the way in the constructor and before render, including its type and see if anything unexpected happens. Sorry for not helping. Fijne dag :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by calling the addSubQuestion function on handleCourseChange(). This forced the subquestions to re-render.